# Generating a PRN File using java

Tags: java, printing

I need to create a prn file using java. Did a basic googling to find what a prn file is all about and its contents. Now anybody out there can help with a sample code for generating one such file or API's that  can be used ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm curious about your need for PRN files since we're in the year 2012. Why not [PostScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript)?

Comment: Requirement was to generate a PRN file.. and i am bound to it.. :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [.PRN file generation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757004/prn-file-generation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Print to file with Java](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/print/print-to-file-with-java) you see, that it is just setting the destination of the print job.

There is the small problem, that what would have been sent to the printer is captured. So the same printer / printer driver has to be selected. Also the printer dialog might already propose in the UI "Print to file."